# What are the differences between layers and extensible-effects?

Tags: haskell, monads

The [extensible effects](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible-effects) library and the [layers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/layers) library appear to have the same goals (making it easy to compose different effects together).
Both talk about the advantages they offer over mtl, but neither makes reference to the other. Can both accomplish the same thing? Does one subsume the other? Does each have some feature that the other lacks?

Answer (score 10):

While I'm in no way experienced with any of those, it's quite straighforward from [the articles](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/exteff.pdf).

While `layers` are rather building upon MTL, `exteff` is a wholly different approach. `exteff` defines one monad that contains information about its effects in its type. `exteff` claims to solve the problem of monad ordering, i.e. if monads A and B are interchangable, the classic approach would make `A (B a)` and `B (A a)` different types. In `exteff` they're the same.

From the [interface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/layers-0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Interface-Reader.html) of `layers` it seems that it didn't solve that problem.

Comment: The github page of `extensible-effects` provides describes some problems with the package, from which only one applies to GHC > 7.8, namely:
`Common functions can't be grouped using typeclasses, e.g. the ask and getState functions can't be grouped with some [...]` (https://github.com/suhailshergill/extensible-effects). Could you tell more about how it applies to layers package? I think we all would be interested in seeing the problem from different "angles". cc: @ibotty

Answer (score 3):

adding to polkovnikov's answer, `extensible-effects` are initially encoded effects and the effects in `layers` (and `mtl`) are final encoded. both approaches have advantages and disadvantages, and perform better or worse in some scenarios.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? In what specific scenarios does one or other approach perform better or worse?

Comment: i will come back to that answer when i update the [benchmark](https://github.com/feuerbach/freemonad-benchmark) to also test the cases where free monads work better.

Comment: i guess i won't have time for a long while. the gist is, that with mtl/layers (or more accurately: transformers) you pay whenever you add a new transformer. lifting through `t (t1 (t2 (t3 m)))` is pretty expensive and not neccessary with a free monad-like approach as `extensible-effects` is using. but: with just one transformer it is **way** faster than extensible effects. that's what you can see in the benchmark i linked.